# data sufficiency problem (from a university entrance exam) involving an absolute value equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

This question is from my country’s (Indonesia) university entrance exam, called [UTBK (also SNBT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNBT). I'm very confused about this data sufficiency problem.

Is the set $\{x\,|\; x < -1 \; \text{or} \; x > 5, \; x \; \text{is a real number}\}$ the solution set for $|m − 3x| > n$? Decide whether statements (1) and (2) below are sufficient to answer the question.

(1) $\;m = 6$ and $n = -9$

(2) $\;m + n = -3$

(A) $\;$Statement (1) ALONE is sufficient but statement (2) ALONE is not sufficient.

(B) $\;$Statement (2) ALONE is sufficient but statement (1) ALONE is not sufficient.

(C) $\;$BOTH statements TOGETHER are sufficient, but NEITHER statement ALONE is sufficient.

(D) $\;$EACH statement ALONE is sufficient.

(E) $\;$Statements (1) and (2) TOGETHER are not sufficient.

**My question:**

From statement (1) we can get $x \in (-\infty, \, \infty).$ Is this enough to say that the solution is NOT $x < - 1$ or $x > 5,$ or is this enough to say that the solution is $x < -1$ or $x > 5$?

Comment: Statement (1) specifies exactly what the given equation is, and since every equation has only one solution set, Statement (1) is sufficient to answer the YES/NO question that is asked -- if the given set **is** the solution set of the equation, then the answer is YES; if the given set **is not** the solution set of the equation, then the answer is NO; either way (i.e. regardless), you can answer the question. In particular, you don’t have to solve the equation to know that Statement (1) alone is sufficient. At this point, you know the answer is not (C) or (E). **(continued)**

Comment: To make further progress, you now need to consider whether Statement (2) alone is sufficient. Perhaps someone else (or you?) can post a full answer to this data sufficiency question.